# Querying client info in Google Activity

Tags: google-chrome, google-takeout, google-search-history

In Google's [My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/) it's possible to see the device that was used to see in the Details tab, but this metadata isn't searchable. I've downloaded my browsing history from the [Takeout](http://takeout.google.com/) service, but in the resulting BrowserHistory.json file all of the entries have the same `"client_id"`, which seems like a bug. Is there anyway to query history items from a specific device?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I was looking at the wrong items and associating them with a device incorrectly. I think `clientid` is different for e.g. desktop and mobile devices